Im getting an Error setting up Firebase Authentication in my react native mobile application(createUserWithEmailAndPassword)
Firebase.JS
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; 
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

RegisterScreen.js

import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const RegisterScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const register = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("User created!");
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    console.log("Inside register!");
  };

My Error:

ERROR  TypeError: _firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start?authuser=0#web
I have tried moving around the import statements so it's all on one page.
I have tried clearing the cache in expo.
